# TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' for 'datetime.date' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe

```
timestamp
2020-08-26
2020-08-27
2020-08-28
```

I want it to look like this

```
timestamp
2020-08-26 00:00:00
2020-08-27 00:00:00
2020-08-28 00:00:00
```

I tried

```
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strftime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

but it gives an issue TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' for 'datetime.date' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object

Appreciate your help

Comment: how about https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: `df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this,

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot convert input [99    2021-04-06
98    2021-04-07
97    2021-04-08
96    2021-04-09
95    2021-04-12
         ...    
4     2021-08-19
3     2021-08-20
2     2021-08-23
1     2021-08-24
0     2021-08-25
Name: timestamp, Length: 100, dtype: object] of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> to Timestamp

Comment: another error occured AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values